# FFmpeg rotated transparent images colorfill not working properly

Tags: image, image-processing, ffmpeg, rotation, image-rotation

I am scaling and rotating a transparent (spade.png) image and placing it as overlay on an input image and save the output.png. This is my command:

> ffmpeg -y -i input.png -i spade.png -filter_complex [1]scale=120:114,setsar=1,format=bgra,rotate=0.78:**c=none**:ow=rotw(0.78):oh=roth(0.78)[s];[0][s]overlay=728-114*sin(0.78):177[out] -pix_fmt bgra -strict experimental -s 640x360 -map [out] output.png

shovel.png (250x238) :

### [image: shovel]

When i don't scale spade.png, it is displaying ok:

### [image: ok]

But when i **scale + rotate spade.png**, the **colorfill** is not working properly:

### [image: problem]

Is this a known ffmpeg bug? Or am I using the **-filter_complex** parameters in the wrong order? Should I use another pix_frmt? Any idea's? Thanks

Comment: Change to `c=black@0`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! If you post it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `c=black@0`. This will fill up the padded area with black but with an alpha of 0, so during overlay, those pixels aren't overlaid.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but it's working for me with "c=black@0" but not "c=black@" . Still great thanks for pointing out the alpha setting.